# Which methods use in Linq to force a retrieving data from database

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

When i use this query, i don't retrieve data from database:

```
var query = db.Table.Where(x => x.id_category.HasValue).Select(x => x.Id);
```

But if i use this, i'll retrieve data:

```
var dataRetrieved = query.ToList();
```

---

Which others methods, like `ToList()`, i can force a retrieving data?

Comment: Thats how its supposed to work. Linq is evaluated when you iterate through the values, `ToList` forces the iteration to happen and thus the query to execute. You can get the same to happen by using a `foreach` or any other iteration through the query.

Comment: Any metod which materializes the result will execute the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ works by building up a series of query commands, and waits until the last possible moment to execute them.  In order to force execution, you have to ask the query for "real" data, not just a description of the steps to get it.

According to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738633%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> LINQ queries are always executed **when the query variable is iterated over**, not when the query variable is created....
>
> To force immediate execution of a query that does not produce a singleton value, you can **call the ToList method, the ToDictionary method, or the ToArray method** on a query or query variable....
>
> You could also force execution by **putting the foreach or For Each loop immediately after the query expression**, but by calling ToList or ToArray you cache all the data in a single collection object.

Answer (score 3):

Besides what **BJ Myers** and **Ebad Massod** already explained, there are also operators which return single value and that are executed immediately, such as:

- **First**, **FirstOrDefault**, **Last**, **LastOrDefault**, **Single**, **SingleOrDefault**

Also, LINQ Aggregate Functions return a single value and are executed immediately, such as:

- **Average**, **Count**, **Max**, **Min**, **Sum**

Here is a nice MSDN article: [**Classification of Standard Query Operators by Manner of Execution**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution)

Answer (score 2):

The select returns an `IEnumerable`, which is a sequence of values to invoke a transform function on. So it depends on you what transformation you want? you want list or array? you can also traverse through and manipulate each piece independently using a foreach loop. Following [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9eekhta0(v=vs.100).aspx) will give you an idea of what you can do with your values.